# Setting combo box to value dynamically retrieved from database in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, combobox

I have a task that I need to retrieve data from the database and set it in the Combo Box. Fortunately, I have done it.

Now, I have a Search Button which retrieves the data relevant in these text and combo boxes. My Issue is, After I click Search Button all my combo box and text box selected values become empty. How can I set those same data after clicking Search button ?

My Code Effort is,

```
<?php
$sql="select cat_id,cat_name from disease_category group by cat_id ";
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){

  if(isset($_REQUEST['cat_name'])&&$_REQUEST['cat_name']==$row[cat_name])
  {
echo "<option value=$row[cat_id] selected='selected' >$row[cat_name]</option>";
  } 
  Else
  {
   echo  "<option value=$row[cat_id]>$row[cat_name]</option>";
  }
}
?>
```

My SEARCH button code,

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['SUBMIT']))
{
$cat=$_REQUEST['cat'];
$subcat=$REQUEST['subcat']
$sel=mysql_query("SELECT * from table_name where cat_id like '$cat%' AND sub_id like   '$sub_cat%'AND survier like '$survier%' ")
}
```

Comment: where is your search button code..

Comment: more information is needed to help you with this issue. what is your goal? where is the input text code/processing code?

Comment: @Indra , I have updated my search button code by editing the question.

Comment: What i m understanding with your que is.. you want keep your  text box and combobox value setted after your search query processed and you returns to the same page with search result.. m i right??

Comment: @ Indra, Yes Exactly. The same am looking for. What I achieved is, I did all the process for Search and the only thing is can not bring the same data in combo box.

Comment: @robotsushi Yes, my goal is to taking the data from database and make it into combo and text boxes and finally doing a search regarding the values. Everything I did, where I am missing is While search result is showing that time i am loosing all the data in combo and text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty simple. I still don't fully understand what you're trying to do. But if all you want is to dynamically populate an options list based on the results of a SQL query.

```
<?php
$sql = '
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `my_table`
';
$query = mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
print '<select name="dropdown">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    print '<option value="'. $row['cat_id'] .'"';
    if (
        isset($_REQUEST['cat_name']) &&
        $_REQUEST['cat_name'] == $row['cat_name']
    ) { print ' selected="selected"'; }
    print '>'. $row['cat_name'] .'</option>';
}
print '</select>';
?>
```

You should be able to modify the SELECT query to fit your needs, and modify content within the while() loop, as well. That should get you going if I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @robotshshi You are life saver. Thanks..! I sorted out this issue.

Comment: @user3269461, no problem! I'm glad I was able to assist.